# Vanishing element using jQuery slideUp

Tags: jquery

I'm working through an issue that is causing a single element to vanish after the 2nd toggle of an element.

When it initially runs, there are 3 buttons visible for each section. To reproduce click on the section that is not expanded, click on the other, and then click back to the original section you started with. The "Online Form" button vanishes.

The culprit is this line, but I have not figured out what is causing this.

```
$('.FormsHeader a').removeClass('current').nextAll().slideUp(430);
```

Here is a link to the current version of the fiddle I'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/ddub/4SZGc/2/

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose this is in IE correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Description of `SlideUp()`

> If .slideDown() is called on an unordered list () and its
>
> elements have position (relative, absolute, or fixed), the effect may
>   not work properly in IE6 through at least IE9 unless the  has
>   "layout." To remedy the problem, add the position: relative; and zoom:
>   1; CSS declarations to the ul.

even the TAG is not `ul` and not for `slideUp()`, try to set css property: `zoom:1` and `position: relative`

Hope it helps