# SlideUp() causes vanish of an element (in IE10)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, slidetoggle, slideup

Similar question link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077394/vanishing-element-using-jquery-slideup), since no one has anwsered it and due to it's complexity, I am making a new and more specific one.

**Criteria:**

When a button gets clicked, I used `SlideUp()` to hide a corresponding `div` section, and use `SlideDown()` to display it again. however, it works all fine in **Chrome** and **Firefox**, but **not** in **IE10**. **The button vanishes after** `SlideUp()`.

Demo code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qNA/) (**NB**: Demo only shows the code I am using and works fine anywhere, but in my local environment, same code will vanish the button when slideUp get triggered **IN IE10**)

Comment: If the demo works in IE10, it's something else in your code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Your demo code work fine in IE9

Comment: Check your HTML markup on your site, something should be invalid as a missing closing TAG

Comment: @ahren but why it works without a problem in other browsers in my local environment ?

Comment: @Bizzon thanks Biz, haven't tested in IE9 yet

Comment: Unfortunately, not all browsers are created equal. You should add more of your code until you can replicate the bug in a closed environment. Until there's an actual trackable/viewable bug, we can't help.

Comment: @ahren working on it now, thanks

Comment: @ahren found reason now, based on the description of SlideUp():If .slideDown() is called on an unordered list (<ul>) and its <li> elements have position (relative, absolute, or fixed), the effect may not work properly in IE6 through at least IE9 unless the <ul> has "layout." To remedy the problem, add the position: relative; and zoom: 1; CSS declarations to the ul. NB: event not for ul, **Zoom: 1** is the key

Comment: Ah interesting. If you write that up as an answer and accept it, it might help someone in the future `=)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on "Additional notes" of [SlideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/):

If .`slideDown()` is called on an unordered list `ul` and its `li` elements have `position` (`relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`), the effect may not work properly in IE6 through at least IE9 unless the `ul` has "layout." To remedy the problem, add the `position: relative`; and `zoom: 1`; CSS declarations to the `ul`.

My case isn't relevant to TAG `ul` and `li`, but when I add css property: `zoom: 1` it works in **IE8**, **IE9**, **IE10** now.